# simple solution to run third party javascript-tags in paralell? ("asyncronously")?

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

is there any  simple solution to run third party javascript-tags in paralell?

*just a few scripts on a html page, which shall not load one after another/sequencial
i know for advertisments it works useing an adserver like doubleclick but that is not necessary here and its not only ads
some need to stay able to analyse the html content the user-agent, ip, referrer or more*

examples,  *that you may very well know* :

1.

```
<script src="http://another-ad-service.com/get-js.aspx?&cwadformat=728*90"</script>
```

2.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var 1a_account   = '12345';
var 1a_zonesize  = '12345-5';
var 1a_adtype    = 'js';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://agency1a.somewhere/12345.js"></script>
```

3.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--//<![CDATA[
   document.MAX_ct0 ='';
   var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://an-advertisment-agency.honolulu...'
   var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
   document.write ("zoneid=12345");document.write("&amp;nodis=1");
   document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
   if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
   document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : 
   (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
   document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
   if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
   if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
   if ((typeof(document.MAX_ct0) != 'undefined') && 
   (document.MAX_ct0.substring(0,4) == 'http')) {
       document.write ("&amp;ct0=" + escape(document.MAX_ct0));
   }
   if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
   document.write ("'></scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>--></script>
```

4.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'website.edu']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ?
    'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.gooooogle-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> window.google_analytics_uacct = "UA-12345-2"; </script>
```

Comment: No matter what you do (except when using webworkers) Javascript runs in one thread, meaning it executes just one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

When load external JavaScript files, you can add the `async` attribute to your script tag.

`<script src="http://another-ad-service.com/get-js.aspx?&cwadformat=728*90" async></script>`

The script needs to be self-sufficient and not depend on other code you are loading before that script, though.

Comment: Yay, that's really simple! :D   
But it will only work for the first example? 
What will be a solution for all 4 examples?

Comment: unfortunately even the first example does not load at all like that.
i tried with the lastest firefox

Comment: That the first example does not work for you might have other reasons. The [async attribute on the script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script) works in all modern browsers. Can you post a real URL that is not working for you, please?